# How to get started on implementing a virtual machine?

Tags: vmware, virtualization, virtual-machine, qemu, bochs

I have recently become interested in implementing a basic x86 virtual machine. I think that it would be one the best ways to **completely** understand the way the x86 architecture works.

Other than the code base of open source VMMs like bochs, QEMU, kvm, or xen, what resources would you recommend that I look into to get started?

Comment: Thanks to Johannes Trushnigg (http://truschnigg.info) for suggesting that I look into the source code of lguest (http://lguest.ozlabs.org/), which is simple enough to be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

While looking at the simple hypervisor seems very interesting, I would recommend you start even simpler, by just writing your assembled instructions directly to the bootsector of a disk image (i.e. a bootloader, just not necessarily one that loads another OS). This way you get to start in "real mode", with access to all privileged instructions. I found the best place to start was here: [MikeOS handbook](http://mikeos.berlios.de/handbook-user.html). It gives you everything you need to get started in just a few minutes, but also goes on to provide a fully working operating system.